# MS-Access Enumerations (specifically V2007/2010)

Tags: vba, ms-access, enums

This question is about MS-Access enumerations (specifically for 2007/2010).

How can I reduce the lines of codes where I have the same color enumerations to control color choices passed to a function.

```
Public Enum lngColor1
    Black = 0
    Maroon = 128
    Green = 32768
    Olive = 32896
    Navy = 8388608
    Purple = 8388736
    Teal = 8421376
    Gray = 8421504
    silver = 12632256
    Red = 255
    Lime = 65280
    Yellow = 65535
    Blue = 16711680
    Fuchsia = 16776960
    White = 16777215
End Enum

Public Enum lngColor2
    Black = 0
    Maroon = 128
    Green = 32768
    Olive = 32896
    Navy = 8388608
    Purple = 8388736
    Teal = 8421376
    Gray = 8421504
    silver = 12632256
    Red = 255
    Lime = 65280
    Yellow = 65535
    Blue = 16711680
    Fuchsia = 16776960
    White = 16777215
End Enum

Function WhatEver(ByVal lngXColor1 as lngColor1, ByVal lngXColor2 as lngColor2)
    ' do what ever with the function parameters
End Function
```

I have tried defining the colors as their own enum and the put the enum in lngColor1 and lngColor2
but IntelliSense only shows the name of the color enumeration and not the color choices themselves.

I actually have 9 enumerations with the same 15 color choices.

Comment: I tried declaring the colors as an enumeration and then specifing the function parameters as lngColorZ,
but this caused an ambiguous error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your requirements, but see below. You can define a `Type` object to wrap the Enums, and pass it to the function.

```
Public Type ColorType
    Color1 As lngColor1
    Color2 As lngColor2
    '...
End Type
```

---

```
Function WhatEver(ByRef myColorType As ColorType)
    
    Dim x As lngColor1, y As lngColor2
    
    x = myColorType.Color1
    y = myColorType.Color2
    
    Debug.Print x
    Debug.Print y

End Function
```

---

Lastly, calling your function.

```
Sub T()

    Dim ct As ColorType
    
    ct.Color1 = lngColor1.Purple
    ct.Color2 = lngColor2.Fuchsia
    
    Dim r
    r = WhatEver(ct)

    ' 8388736 
    ' 16776960 

End Sub
```

---

Do you really need to declare the same color Enum 15 times? Why not just once, and assign it to 15 different properties?

```
Color1 As lngColor1
Color2 As lngColor1
Color3 As lngColor1
'...
```

There are also a number of built-in colors, e.g. `vbBlack`, `vbYellow` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **single** enumeration for the colors works!  I had 2 other enumerations that I had NOT commented out, so once they were commented out everything worked.

```
Public Enumeration lngColorZ
    ' colors go here
End Enumeration


Function WhatEver(ByVal lngXColor1 as lngColorZ, ByVal lngXColor2 as lngColorZ)
    ' do what ever with the function parameters
End Function
```

Above works! Thanks for the comments.